# Is there a terminal command or other way to compltely turn off a Raspberry Pi camera?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi camera and use my Raspberry Pi a lot, but the camera has a tendency to overheat. Is there a terminal command to turn off the camera and to turn it back on when I need it?

It is not controlled via USB, but the CSI camera connector.

Comment: You may be more likley to get an answer at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Which model Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @BenVoigt I am using the RPi 2 Model B V1.1

Comment: Based on [the schematic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-B-Plus-V1.2-Schematics.pdf) the power pin for the camera connector is not switched, nor is there any reset pin.
So you're looking for some software reset function through the Broadcom-proprietary driver stack.

Answer (score 3):

The RPI does not have a PCI bus, so we cannot use the standard Linux command to turn off the onboard camera. Just for the sake of completeness, I will show you how to do both things, in a RPI an in a normal pc.

**RPI**

The RPI camera can be turned off at boot. There's a file, `/boot/config.txt`, where you will need this setting:

```
start_x=0
```

while setting `start_x=1` turns it on.

If you want to do this on the run, you may try (I do not have one to try this on) the following at a pyhton prompt:

```
 import picamera
 from time import sleep
 sleep(500)
```

and see whether this actually solves your overheating problem. Of course, you will need to have installed

```
  sudo apt-get install python-picamera
```

**Pc with PCI bus**

The command is

```
 echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.3/bConfigurationValue
```

to turn it off, and of course `echo 1 > ...` to turn it on again. The only problem is that the bus address `1-1.3` is correct for **my** pc. You find your address by looking at the output of

```
 # lsusb -t 
  ...............
  :  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

You see in this output a `Class=Video` object, located at Bus 1, dev 3. Now you can go to

```
 # cd /sys/bus/usb/devices/; ls 
 1-0:1.0  1-1.2      1-1.3      2-0:1.0  2-1.5      2-1.6:1.0   2-1.6:1.2  2-1.6:1.5  2-1.6:1.8  3-2      3-3:1.0  4-0:1.0  usb3
```

The only 1-3 device is `1-1.3`. You enter the directory and double check that this is your video cam by

```
# cat id{Vendor,Product}
   1bcf
   288e
```

which you can compare with the output of

```
 # lsusb 
  ................
  Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:288e Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
```

A Google search shows that 1bcf is indeed a VideoCam. `1-1.3` is the code to insert in the command above.

Comment: What if this isn't a USB device, but instead attached by a ribbon cable?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae why do I need to import picamera to use sleep(500)? Is there anything missing in your python code?

Comment: You can do the same sleep in bash. Simply run sleep 500. No need to import picamera.